# Android BLE - Do Advertising Packet Numbers Exist?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a my phone to connect and alter characteristics within a BLE module, which then sends the message down a mesh of similar nodes. However, I need to be able to make this communication "smarter."

Essentially, I'd like to know if there is an "advertising number" that increments each time I connect and change data within the BLE module. That is, I would like to run a service to check the advertising number of a node without connecting to it. Thus, if there is an updated packet held by the BLE module, the device should then connect to that node and read the message. However, I do not want the devices (phones) to connect to these nodes unless there is an update.

The problem is that if the phones connect to these BLE nodes every so often, without checking to see if they really "need to," then there is a chance that they will miss a message being pushed through the mesh since the BLE nodes can only be paired with a single device at one time.

If the answer is no, I would greatly appreciate a suggestion. The main idea is that I do not want to miss information being passed. Because, once again, when connected to a node with a device, the node will not listen to other nodes in the mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like this standardized. You will need to implement it yourself.

It seems you already have a good idea to include a number in the advertising data that gets incremented each time there is a change.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I'll have to look into modifying the data.